# Computer force restarts when graphics card is installed

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, gpu

Specs:
Intel Core i7 4770k with Corsair H100i
Asrock Z87-ITX
Corsair Vengeance 8GB x2
Rosewill HIVE 650W
EVGA GeForce GTX 770
Runs to monitor through HDMI cable from GPU

I've been troubleshooting a few problems recently, this is my most recent one. My power supply is the only one thats new, but everything else is only a few months old. I've ran the system with everything but the graphics card, so I'm pretty sure the problem lies somewhere there, but I have no idea how to go about it.

Just yesterday, I had the entire system working for a while. Everything was initially in a water cooling system and after taking it all down, the only thing that didn't have any kind of cooling was the GPU so I just had a room fan blowing on it. I managed to run it, so I ran a benchmark to see if the GPU still performed well while monitoring temps. It raised quickly to 80 degrees, probably cause the water block was still on it, and ended up restarting the whole computer. I didn't try it again.

Today, I took out the GPU, removed the water block, and then reinstalled it.

The symptoms I've seen so far after I've installed the graphics card:

When turned on, computer boots up and starts loading windows, only to forcefully restart, and boot up again where I am greeted with the option to go in safe mode.

When I do go into safe mode, I have a limited time to do anything as the screen goes black without warning.

The same thing happens in the bios, except much quicker.

The CMOS battery seems to work fine, as the date and time in bios remains correct. I have no other computer to test my GPU. I have two power supplies, one listed above, the other a Rosewill 750W.

So, is my graphics card dead? I still have warranty on it, but I'd at least like to try to find a fix.

Comment: Its had to understand the problem.  Your graphics card shouldn't need anything except its own cooling system unless your overclocking the heck out of it.  Please provide more information.  I am going to assume your not overclocking the GPU which means the fact its getting that hot under normal loads there is something else going on.  Your CPU cooling system would not cause your GPU to overheat that much.

Comment: Did you _remove_ the GPU's existing cooling system? If you did that and ran it with only a room fan blowing on the GPU, you have probably fried it. That could also happen if you did not properly attach the water block.

Comment: What is confusing about this setup is the fact the `Corsair H100i` in use is a closed cooling system.  The user clearly isn't using an actual custom water cooing setup based on the description of the system.

Comment: Eh everything else is in its own water cooling loop. The CPU is the only one with an AIO. I removed the water block for the gpu and kept the fan concentrated on its core. And I wouldn't say it was under normal loads. I was using the EVGA physics benchmark to test the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

The GPU's cooling system cools many components, not just the GPU. Without a proper cooling setup, the GPU itself can monitor its own temperature and throttle, but other components (RAM, VRM) can't. Likely other components on the graphics card fried by running without proper cooling. But the only way to know for sure is to reinstall proper cooling and test.

If you try to put the original cooler back on, make sure you do it exactly right. It likely has to make proper thermal contact with more components than just the GPU.

Comment: So if I use the GPU with the stock cooler and it works, that obviously means nothing is fried. If it doesn't work, how exactly does that prove the card is fried? Sorry if noob questions, but I haven't ran a graphics card hard enough to fry it before.

Comment: If it doesn't work, that doesn't prove the card is fried. You'd have to troubleshoot in that case. But you can't do any useful testing until you fix the cooling.